# Will iAds be loaded, if I hide the ADBannerView?

Tags: iphone, sdk, load, hidden, iad

I know Apple recommends just placing the adview offscreen,
incase there is an error, loading an iAd,
but I would like to hide it using `[adView setHidden: YES];`.
If I do so, will the view check for new ads available?

In the simulator sure it will load the Test Ads,
but will it also work after releasing the app onto actual devices from the AppStore?

SideSwipe

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should work on real device.